# How to install Vuze torrent client from the official website on Linux?

Tags: linux, software-installation, bittorrent

After reading the [installation steps of Vuze from the official website on Linux](https://wiki.vuze.com/w/Initial_Setup_Guide#Manual_install_from_Vuze_website), I need to install it properly, as the instructions are rather short and incomplete.

The particular OS in question is Linux Mint 18.3, but this should be a generic question covering most of Linuxes.

Comment: Vuze turned into a horrible PoS a couple of years ago. Adverts might be involved, my memory is a bit fuzzy. Used it in Mac and switched to Transmission.

Comment: That is why I made a comment and not an answer. Relax mate.

Comment: Sorry about intruding again. Vuze created their own network to promote multimedia and social network wether you like it or not, that is why I abandoned it. Being a Java binary was a small part of it, actually.

Comment: It used to be the their parallel networking still keep running no matter what the mode, and their networking client was also classified as malware. No idea how is the situation nowadays - they took heat and a big backlash because of it -  however Vuze vs transmission would still go against my guidelines of KISS and keeping the least amount of software installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we begin, note that you need `openjdk-8-jre` or higher installed; Without it, Vuze won't run.

1. Download the tarball from the official website to the `~/Downloads` directory:

   https://www.vuze.com/download.php
2. Suppose, you don't have a `~/bin` directory for your programs, so you need to create one; or generally speaking, you need to create a directory to store Vuze program files permanently:

   ```
   mkdir --mode 0755 ~/bin
   ```
3. Move the tarball you have downloaded to this directory:

   ```
   mv ~/Downloads/VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2 ~/bin
   ```
4. Go to the `~/bin` directory:

   ```
   cd ~/bin
   ```
5. Extract the archive:

   ```
   tar -xjf VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2
   ```
6. Remove the tarball, as we don't need it anymore:

   ```
   rm VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2
   ```
7. It will create the following directory:

   ```
   vuze
   ```
8. Go to that directory:

   ```
   cd vuze
   ```
9. (Recommendation) As the official download page does provide neither SHA-256 sum, nor a GPG signature, there is no way of checking, if the downloaded file has not been tempered with, so you may for example, upload the main program file to [VirusTotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/) to check it out:

   ```
   Azureus2.jar
   ```
10. Convert the following files from DOS to Linux line endings:

    ```
    dos2unix vuze.schemas vuze.desktop LICENSES.txt
    ```
11. Copy the icons and a related file into appropriate place:

    ```
    sudo cp vuze.png vuze.torrent.png vuze.schemas /usr/share/pixmaps/
    ```
12. Open the desktop file with any text editor, I used `nano`:

    ```
    nano vuze.desktop
    ```
13. Edit the line starting with:

    ```
    Exec=
    ```
14. To contain:

    ```
    Exec=/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/bin/vuze/vuze %f
    ```
15. Copy the desktop file to system menu:

    ```
    sudo cp vuze.desktop /usr/share/applications
    ```
16. Copy the desktop file to your desktop and make it "Trusted" as Ubuntu says, essentially this is done by making it executable:

    ```
    cp vuze.desktop ~/Desktop
    chmod 755 ~/Desktop/vuze.desktop
    ```